# docker commands not working with latest version

Tags: windows, docker, cmd

The following commands used to work before, but as of `Docker version 19.03.8 - build afacb8b` they are not working.

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) -f
docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

This is the error I'm getting for the first docker command to stop all containers:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a
See 'docker stop --help'.
```

Comment: I am running that build on multiple machines and these commands are working just as they used to.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: @NickODell added the error

Comment: `-a` should be evaluated as a part of `docker ps` and not be visible to `stop` (the error implies otherwise). This is not a problem with docker. Either there is something wrong with your system and how it evaluates commands, or you are actually using some different command than the one posted here. For example, this would cause the error  `docker stop $(docker ps -q) -a`

Comment: Got it to work using powershell but cmd is not working. Probably because of $( )

Answer (score 8):

In case of using Windows OS, Faced similar issue, got it working when executed the command from windows PowerShell, preferably with admin privilege's.

Comment: I ran PowerShell with administrator privilege and its working fine now.